# API documentation for Android SDK is not working

Tags: here-api

For the last couple of days it is impossible to access any documentation about APIs for Android SDK.

There is an error page with information:

> "Unfortunately, the page you're looking for doesn't seem to exist."

[Example link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-guidance-navigationmanager-navigationmode.html)

Comment: Could you provide some example search terms you were using that resulted in broken links?  The one you provided seems broken but others seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The links have been cleaned up a bit, please update your bookmarks to: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/maps.html

Comment: I am not using bookmarks. Description of the SDK classes is not available via search function on the Here Maps website.